# How to use strtok

Tags: c

Below is a solution to the codewars training.
https://www.codewars.com/kata/59f4a0acbee84576800000af/train/c

```
Test Crashed
Caught unexpected signal: SIGSEGV (11). Invalid memory access.
```

I get an error message like this, what's wrong?
I think it's probably part of the strtok function, but please tell me what's wrong.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
double pos_average(char *s, unsigned n)
{
  char **matrix;
  char *p;
  unsigned int i, j, k;
  unsigned int subst_len = ( strchr(s,',') - s  ) / sizeof(char);
  double count = 0;
  
  matrix = (char**)calloc( n + 1  ,sizeof(char*) );
  if(!matrix) exit(0);
  
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    matrix[i] = (char*)calloc( subst_len + 1 ,sizeof(char) );
    if(!matrix[i]) exit(0);
  }
    
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if(i == 0){
      p = strtok(s, " ");
      strncpy(matrix[i], p, subst_len);
    }
    else{
      p = strtok(NULL," ");
      strncpy(matrix[i], p, subst_len);
    }
  }  

  for(i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
  {
    for(j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
    {
      for(k = 0; k < subst_len; k++)
      {
        if(matrix[i][k] == matrix[j][k]) count++;
      }     
    }        
  }
   
  for(i = 0; i < n; i++) free(matrix[i]);
  free(matrix);
  
  return (count / (  ( (double)n * ( (double)n - 1.0 ) )  / 2.0 ) ) * 100.0;
}
```

Comment: So you haven't tried running it yourself in a debugger, to see where the fault occurs?

Comment: `strtok` can return NULL. You need to check for that and handle it.

Comment: @Useless I'm not very used to debugging yet, but I did debugging. Then the values of the variables "matrix [i]" and "count" were correct. Therefore, I think that the usage of "strtok" is strange and the memory is being accessed illegally.

Comment: @Retired Ninja Will I get an error if I don't check it?

Comment: Is the string passed via `s` modifiable?

Comment: @Gerhardh Since the number of characters is specified by the argument of "strncpy", commas are not copied.

Comment: @Dmitri 　Isn't it changeable because it doesn't have "const"?

Comment: If you're passing in a string literal, or a `char *` pointing to one, it may be effectively read only.  And since `strtok()` modifies the string when it finds a token, that might cause your crash.  Try putting the string in a (non-const) array first.

Comment: @Gerhardh   ("6900690040, 4690606946, 9990494604", 3u)　It is assigned to the argument like this. It is separated by a space by "strtok".

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I missed the spaces after the commas in the example string.

Comment: @Dmitri　　Is it all right to prepare an array for copying and copy it there?

Comment: Whatever you want, as long as it isn't read only.  `char s[] = "string";` should work, but `char *s = "string";` may not.  Or you can copy it to an array or dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @Dmitri I got it. I learn something new.